# In React Typescript how to define type for ...rest parameter for native html elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to filter some props and then pass down the rest of the props to a native html element like so:

```
const Placeholder = (
  display: boolean,
  ...rest: Array<React.LabelHTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement>>
) => <label {...rest} />
```

The problem is that this is giving me this error:

```
Type '{ length: number; toString(): string; toLocaleString(): string; pop(): LabelHTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement> | undefined; push(...items: LabelHTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement>[]): number; ... 28 more ...; flat<U>(this: U[][][][][][][][], depth: 7): U[]; flat<U>(this: U[][][][][][][], depth: 6): U[]; flat<U>(this: U[]...' has no properties in common with type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LabelHTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement>, HTMLLabelElement>'.ts(2559)
```

How would I define the types for the `...rest` parameters for a native html element like a `label` in Typescript / React?

Comment: try `Array<React.LabelHTMLAttributes<T>>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of `label` is: `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.LabelHTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement>, HTMLLabelElement>`

So relying on this, something like this should work:

```js
interface Props
  extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.LabelHTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement>,
    HTMLLabelElement
  > {
  display: boolean;
}

const Placeholder = ({ display, ...rest }: Props) => <label {...rest} />;

const App = () => <Placeholder display htmlFor="form" />;
```

Also, note that since the first argument is `props` is being destructured as an object (so `...rest` is the remaining props as an object), not as an array.

Comment: Excellent. I frequently find myself on a quest to discover types like these.. how did you know exactly which types to use without a lot of trial and error?

Comment: Using Codesandbox or VSCode, hovering over the `label` in `<label {...rest} />` will show you the types. Additionally, `cmd + click` on label (on macOS in VSCode) will open the type definitions.